# Getting readable date from ISO

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I'm using `vue.js` and `moment.js` and I can't get this date into a readble format.

```
2022-03-16T13:00:00.000000Z
```

I'm looking for something like 16th March 2022 - 1pm

I've tried this thus far...

```
    var s = '2022-03-16T13:00:00.000000Z';
    var b = s.split(/\D+/);
    console.log( new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6])));
```

and

```
<span>{{ '2022-03-16T13:00:00.000000Z' | moment("DD-MM-YY") }}</span>
```

Comment: Could you please RTFM? 
`let date=new Date('2022-03-16T13:00:00.000000Z')` is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using moment, you can achieve this-

```
moment('2022-03-16T13:00:00.000000Z').format('Do MMMM YYYY - h a') //16th March 2022 - 6 pm
```